# Javascript TextRange object findText method

Tags: javascript, textrange

My problem is that I want to search for a given text (eg a company name) in a selected area of a HTML page. So I used Textrange.findText for it (need IE compatibility). But it only finds a match, if the section doesn't contains `<br>` element.
If the company name is like "some big company", and the HTML is like

```
<p> Some <span>big</span> company</p>
```

than the findText finds it without problem. But otherwise like

```
<p> Some <br> big company</p>
```

the call of findText('Some big company') finds nothing. So I suppose that the problem is with the `<br>` tag, but many page uses this tag to format text with line breaks.

findText reference: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I couldn't find any solution for this myself, maybe you could help. I accept every kind of help or advice. (sorry for mistakes)

Comment: What's your goal?
Do you just want a yes/no result?
Do you want to modify the match?

Comment: Yes, i want to access the range and modify it.